# Does grid2grid exist?

Tags: matlab, grid, mesh

Does anybody know how to pass a known solution on a square grid to a triangular grid? I have been using the `tri2grid` command to pass my solution from a triangular mesh to a square grid, so now I am looking for something like a "grid2grid" function to pass my solution from one grid to another. Does anyone know how to do this?

say I know the solution at the points on a square grid which looks like:

[image]

And what I want is interpolate that solution on the grid below:

[image]

With keeping in mind that coordinates and the solution I have is in matrix form and after the interpolation I want to have them in matrix form again.

Comment: http://mooring.ucsd.edu/software/matlab/doc/toolbox/datafun/grid2tri.html Is this ok for you?

Comment: Not really :( this creates triangulation on a grid what I want is pass solution from one grid to another. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: How do you want to pass solution one grid to another? Just adding more or less element? Why dont you use then interp2?

Comment: I have a known solution on a square grid and I want to see the interpolation of that solution on another grid that I created inside a triangle. Maybe I was not clear enough with my question, hope now it makes more sense.

Comment: Its still unclear. Inside a treiangle? how is the triangle defined? is it a random trianlge inside the grid? is part of a square elemet?

Comment: I make some modifications on the question, maybe that helps :)

Comment: mmm now it makesmore sense, but,in your second image, the lower part goes far from the orinigal (from -12 you want data in -25).  That extrapolation would very probably give you very different results. So, you need to interpolate somedata and extrapolate other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is to use griddata (not advised by Matlab) or scatteredInterpolant (advised).

As I always use griddata (never had any problem with it), I'll give you an answer with it.

```
X=-12:0;
Y=-1:2/11:1;
[X,Y]=ndgrid(X,Y);%size(X) = size(Y)
Z=yourfunc(X,Y);%whatever are your original Z values.
TriX = trianglefunc(Y);%size(TriX)=size(X)=size(Y)
TriZ = griddata(X,Y,Z,TriX,Y);
```

You'll need to define yourself how you make the triangle though. I noticed that only x-axis values are changing but the y-axis ones stay the same. This is why there is no 'TriY'. Also, if your 'TriX' values are outside 'X', the function will return you NaNs for the extrapolated values if I remember well. If you need to extrapolate, as Ander Biguri mentionned, you'll need to use the scatteredInterpolant class.